# How do I check for null or string values ​in columns in the whole dataset in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def check_isnull(self):
df = pd.read_csv(self.table_name)

for j in df.values:
    for k in j[0:]:
        try:
            k = float(k)
            Flag=1
        except ValueError:
            Flag = 0
            break



if Flag==1:
    QMessageBox.information(self, "Information",
                            "Dataset is ready to train.",
                            QMessageBox.Close | QMessageBox.Help)
elif Flag==0:
    QMessageBox.information(self, "Information",
                            "There are one or more non-integer values.",
                            QMessageBox.Close | QMessageBox.Help)
```

Greetings, here is only 40 rows of the dataset I am trying to train it. I want to replace the null or string values ​​that exist here. My existing function for the replacement operation works without any problems. I wanted to write a function that only gives an output to detect them. My function sometimes gives an error, where is the problem?

```
             User ID        Age EstimatedSalary  Female  Male  Purchased
0           15624510  19.000000           19000       0     1          0
1    1581qqsdasd0944  35.000000          qweqwe       0     1          0
2           15668575  37.684211           43000       1     0          0
3                NaN  27.000000           57000       1     0          0
4           15804002  19.000000     69726.81704       0     1          0
..               ...        ...             ...     ...   ...        ...
395         15691863  46.000000           41000       1     0          1
396         15706071  51.000000           23000       0     1          1
397         15654296  50.000000           20000       1     0          1
398         15755018  36.000000           33000       0     1          0
399         15594041  49.000000           36000       1     0          1
```

Comment: Do not include images. Just include the data. Paste the data instead of the image

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
mask = df.apply(lambda col: col.astype(str).str.replace('.','',1).str.isdigit(), axis=0)
```

This will first remove the dots in float numbers. Then check if all chars of a value are numeric. It will return a dataframe where any non numeric value is "False" and any numeric value is (True).

If you need to delete rows that have any of these values you can use:

```
df = df[mask.all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
pd.to_numeric(df['estimated'],errors='coerce')
```

then use this to get rid of those rows and also rows with NANs

```
 df.dropna(subset='estimated')
```

Comment: if the number of columns is more than 1000 will we check one by one ?

Comment: use can use the apply function as follows cols = ['F0', 'F1', 'F2']
Table_1[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce', axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_isnull(self):
    df = pd.read_csv(self.table_name)
    Flag = 1
    for j in df.values:
        for k in j[0:]:
            if k=="nan" or k=="NaN" or k=="NAN" or type(k)==str:
                Flag = 0
```

I created a structure that iterates all data. run times are comparable.

Comment: The thing is that if a column does have sting values, even numeric data in the column will be read as strings. So your if statement will be true for all values in the column. 
Furthermore, k==“Nan” and all other ones as you put them are all redundant since you are checking type is string.

Comment: Looking at it closer. How does this even solve the problem in the question? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When I tried the function for the dataset, there was no problem. I cannot it. I have to look again